# Form showing as a class in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form in my project that is showing up as a class in Solution Explorer.  This is causing a problem since I can't get to the designer.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seeing if there are any hidden files by using the the 'Show All Files' button.  Sounds like your project file might not have all of the files added to it.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix the problem manually by editing your csproj file.

Open it in notepad and search for the filename of the class.  You should see something like this...

```
<Compile Include="frmTest.cs" />
```

Add a subtype called 'Form' like this...

```
<Compile Include="frmTest.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Reload the project.  Visual Studio should now identify the file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that has worked for me in the past is to just add another blank form to the project and that seemed to make the other form show up as a form.  You can then delete the blank form.

I don't know if it will work for you, but it only takes a few moments to try it.

Chris

Comment: +1 saved a lot of hassle of adding the <subtype> tag manually for all the many forms that seemed to have this dropped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove the reference of form related dll and again add and build the project

Answer (score 0):

Press F7 when in code editor to get to the designer. And restarting Visual Studio usually helps.

Comment: F7 didn't bring up the designer and I've restarted Visual Studio but still the form shows up as a class instead of a form and I can only get to the code behind.  Like a form it still has a .Designer.cs and a .resx.

Answer (score -1):

Simply select the form and press Shift+F7. You'll find your form.